# Find indices in each column and intelligently average the values in the same column based on the indices

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have a matrix that every column is independent of the each other. That said, each column has a minimum of `0` and maximum of `1`, it's a probability. However, it's not necessary that each column only contain one `1`. This will create a problem for me as I try to find the indices of each column that consists `1`. The indexes will be used to extract the value of another matrix, let's say position matrix. If it contain two `1`, the values should be averaged. Example code:

```
prob=[rand(4,1) rand(4,1) rand(4,1)];
max_prob_idx=find(prob==1);
%extract from position matrix
pos=rand(4,3);
extracted_pos=pos(max_prob_idx); %this is wrong, look example below
```

From the above code, I will obtain a column vector of `extracted_pos`. This messed up my data extraction. Numerically:

```
prob=[1    0    1 
      0.1  1    0.8
      0.2  0.5  1
      0.3  1    1]

max_prob_idx=[1; 6; 8; 9; 11; 12];

pos=[1 5 9
     2 6 10
     3 7 11
     4 8 12]

extracted_pos=[1; 6; 8; 9; 11; 12]; %6x1 matrix
```

I'm missing something in between so that my final expected `extracted_pos` would be

```
extracted_pos=[1; (6+8)/2; (9+11+12)/3]; %3x1 matrix
```

I know this looks quite messy but I can't think any other way to explain my problem here. Can this be done? Or there is other way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
% generate position matrix
pos = reshape(1:numel(prob),size(prob)); % technically the reshape is not necessary, a vector 1:numel(prob) would do it too, but I find it nicer.
% empty NaN matrix
P = nan(size(prob)); 
% extract 1 values
P(prob==1) = pos(prob==1);  % with real data you might have to make a check with tolerance
% mean of each column
extracted_pos = mean(P,1,'omitnan');
```

`extracted_pos` may of course contain floating point numbers - it's up to you how to handle them

Comment: You're a genius! Thank you so much!

Comment: `nanmean` is from the Stats and ML toolbox. Use `mean` with `'omitnan'` instead